# Ограничения ну уровне приложения или ограничения на уровне БД?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, .net

Допустим есть приложение, которое работает с БД.

Приложение занимается вставкой каких-то записей и какое-то значения должно быть всегда уникальным(Это не первичный ключ).

Например в одной категории не может товара с одинаковыми названиями.

Так вот, на стороне чего лучше делать такие ограничения?

Если делать на стороне БД, то БД сама все проанализирует и вернет ошибку,
если делать на стороне приложения, то понадобится писать логику.

Просто, я глянул некоторые исходники и обнаружил, что ограничения делаются на уровне приложения, а на стороне БД опускаются.

Comment: Надо проверять и там, и там.

Comment: В принципе, если сообщите базе данных ваши ограничения (уникальность, например), база сможет лучше оптимизировать запросы. Так что да, стоит сообщать базе всё, что она в состоянии понять.

Comment: для этих целей делают индексы, проверка на стороне клиента может провалиться: 2 пользователя одновременно решили добавить одинаковые записи, первый проверил всем путем а в это время второй записал в бд свои данные...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Общие ограничения - ограничения предметной области - лучше делать на стороне СУБД, т.к. их разделяют все приложения. Это, помимо контроля над данными, позволит избежать дублирования кода.

Answer (score 3):

Простые проверки типа уникальности поля обычно делают на двух сторонах: и в БД, и в коде. Особенно если используются реляционные БД. Вот почему:

- Наличие ограничений в БД объясняется тем, что БД должна содержать
  валидные и консистентные данные. В случае реляционных БД они уже обладают встроенными средствами таких проверок, поэтому ими пользуются.
- Наличие валидации в коде объясняется тем, что анализировать SQL
  ошибки -- сложно и некрасиво. Плюс, если данные под рукой, проще не ходить в
  базу, а проверить сразу.

Что касается сложной логики валидации, то она обычно реализуется только с одной стороны. Такая логика уже является полноценными бизнес-правилами, а их дублирование чревато. БД же является всего лишь инструментом хранения, который можно и сменить, поэтому чаще всего такая логика находится на стороне кода.